# Fatal error when trying to convert dateformat

Tags: php

I have a datepicker with the format: `d/m/Y`.

I am trying to send the date from the datepicker to my database in the format: `Y-m-d`.

I am using the following script for it:

```
$myDateTime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $single_cal4);
$newSingle_cal4 = $myDateTime1->format('Y-m-d');
```

When I run this script I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /send1.php on line 80
```

Line 80 is:

```
$newSingle_cal4 = $myDateTime1->format('Y-m-d');
```

I am sure that this script is working for other pages. Does someone know why I am getting this error and how I can fix it=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex Howansky is right, you should check if `$myDateTime1` is valid or not by do this:

```
try {
    $myDateTime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $single_cal4);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$newSingle_cal4 = $myDateTime1->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: With this I dont get a fatal error anymore. But I dont understand the reason that the script didnt work. When I echo the $single_cal4 I get: 23/06/2000. And this is d/m/Y

Answer (score 2):

This simply means that `$myDateTime1` is not an object, which means that `DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $single_cal4);` failed, which means that `$single_cal4` is not a valid date. See the docs for [`createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) regarding what it returns when it encounters an error. You'll want to add a check to ensure it worked correctly.

Comment: But in this case the date for $single_cal4 is represented as: `23/06/2000`. Why isnt this a valid date?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the second parameter $single_cal4 as String to function createFromFormat() . Reference http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

The below code will give error because second parameter not passed as string

```
 $myDateTime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', 23/06/2000);
 echo $newSingle_cal4 = $myDateTime1->format('Y-m-d');
```

When it is passed as string, you get the desired result

```
$myDateTime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '23/06/2000');
echo $newSingle_cal4 = $myDateTime1->format('Y-m-d');
```

Out put: 
2000-06-23

I hope this will give some idea to debug.